# Unmarshalling config files in go

Tags: go, viper-go

I am trying to read a config in a json file using the [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) library

```
//config.json
    {
        "currency": {
            "btc": [{
                "api_endpoint": "api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/$address/balance",
                "balance_threshold": 234234.34,
                "wallet_address": "0xsdrsdf",
                "alerts":{
                    "slack": "put slack config here",
                    "sms": "put sms config here"
                },
                "enable_monitoring": true
            }],
            "eth": [{
                "api_endpoint": "some endpoint",
                "balance_threshold" : 2234234.234,
                "wallet_address": "0xsdrsdf",
                "alerts":{
                    "slack": "put slack config here",
                    "sms": "put sms config here"
                },
                "enable_monitoring": true
            }]
        }
    }
```

and config.go like this

```
   func GetConfig() {
        viper.SetConfigName("config") // name of config file (without extension)
        viper.SetConfigType("json")   // REQUIRED if the config file does not have the extension in the name
        viper.AddConfigPath(".")      // path to look for the config file in
        viper.AddConfigPath("$HOME/") // path to look for the config file in
        err := viper.ReadInConfig()   // Find and read the config file
        if err != nil {               // Handle errors reading the config file
            panic(fmt.Errorf("Fatal error config file: %s", err))
        }
        var config config
        viper.Unmarshal(&config)
        fmt.Println(viper.Get("currency"))
        fmt.Printf("Config: %v\n", config["currency"])
    }

    type coreconfig struct {
        APIEndpoint      string  `json:"api_endpoint"`
        BalanceThreshold float64 `json:"balance_threshold"`
        WalletAddress    string  `json:"wallet_address"`
        EnableMonitoring bool    `json:"enable_monitoring"`
        Alerts           map[string]alerts
    }

    type alerts struct {
        Sms   string `json:"sms"`
        Slack string `json:"slack"`
    }

    type currencyconfig map[string][]coreconfig

    type config map[string]currencyconfig
```

The output is printed as empty config

```
[map[btc:[map[alerts:[map[slack:put slack config here sms:put sms config here]] api_endpoint:api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/$address/balance balance_threshold:234234 enable_monitoring:true wallet_address:0xsdrsdf]] eth:[map[alerts:[map[slack:put slack config here sms:put sms config here]] api_endpoint:some endpoint balance_threshold:2.234234e+06 enable_monitoring:true wallet_address:0xsdrsdf]]]] <= This shows that config file is read correctly

Config: map[] <= actual output
```

Comment: `viper.AddConfigPath("$HOME/")` <-- are you sure it expands environment variables?

Comment: I am actually just reading from this `viper.AddConfigPath(".")  `. But yes, it does expand those env variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map[string]string` or `alerts` only in  `coreconfig` struct as your json stucture.

The json tag is used by the `json` package, not by viper. Viper use `github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure` package for unmarshaling, so use `mapstructure` tag.

```
type coreconfig struct {
    APIEndpoint      string  `mapstructure:"api_endpoint"`
    BalanceThreshold float64 `mapstructure:"balance_threshold"`
    WalletAddress    string  `mapstructure:"wallet_address"`
    EnableMonitoring bool    `mapstructure:"enable_monitoring"`
    Alerts           alerts
}
```